# Google Maps won't work when API key is provided

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting alert saying:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The
>   provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized
>   for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the
>   owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key
>   here:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

when using Google Maps with API key.

What I did:

1.Created new API key with setting "Any referer allowed".

2.Deployed on my local webserver Hello World example from documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

3.Replaced API_KEY with newly generated key.

When I access such page, I am getting the alert. How do I fix it?

Comment: you must enable the maps-javascript-API in the API-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dr.Molle said: the problem was with not enabling maps-javascript-API in the console.